# Overiding parent theme functions with a Child theme in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to override the Parent theme function.php file with a function i have in my child themes function.php file but i'm getting a couple of errors. Here's what iv'e done so far..

```
function remove_et_postinfo_meta_actions() {

remove_action('after_setup_theme','et_postinfo_meta',3);
}

add_action('init', 'remove_et_postinfo_meta_actions');


add_action('after_setup_theme', 'cc_et_postinfo_meta', 3);


if ( ! function_exists( 'cc_et_postinfo_meta' ) ){
function cc_et_postinfo_meta( $postinfo, $date_format, $comment_zero, $comment_one, $comment_more          ){
    global $themename;

    $postinfo_meta = '';

    if ( in_array( 'author', $postinfo ) ){
        $postinfo_meta .= ' ' . esc_html__('by',$themename) . ' ' .     et_get_the_author_posts_link();
    }

    if ( in_array( 'date', $postinfo ) )
        $postinfo_meta .= ' ' . esc_html__('on',$themename) . ' ' . get_the_time( $date_format );

    if ( in_array( 'categories', $postinfo ) )
        $postinfo_meta .= ' ' . esc_html__('in',$themename) . ' ' . get_the_category_list(', ');

    if ( in_array( 'comments', $postinfo ) )
        $postinfo_meta .= ' ' . et_get_comments_popup_link( $comment_zero, $comment_one,   $comment_more );

    if ( '' != $postinfo_meta ) $postinfo_meta = __('Posted',$themename) . ' ' . $postinfo_meta;

    echo $postinfo_meta;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the errors you are getting?

As described in the WordPress codex:

> "Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)" *(source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)*

So, it is not possible to override the functions.php file, but you can add your own functions to the functions.php file in your child theme. Be sure to prefix your own function so it won't conflict with the functions in the parent theme.

Comment: The thing is, i'm trying to remove ' | ' from the post meta data. That's all i need to do, but it's included in the theme's function here: if ( in_array( 'date', $postinfo ) )
        $postinfo_meta .= ' | ' . esc_html__('on',$themename) . ' ' . get_the_time( $date_format );

Comment: Also @Sjors, i tried removing the function from the parent theme and replacing it with an updated one.

Comment: And removing that function from the parent and placing it in your child theme didn't help? You're sure it's the right function?

Comment: By the way, if you're not removing the original function from the parent theme the code below won't be executed, because the function already exists:
if ( ! function_exists( 'cc_et_postinfo_meta' ) ){
function cc_et_postinfo_meta ..

Comment: I tried removing the function with:  function remove_et_postinfo_meta_actions() {
remove_action('after_setup_theme','et_postinfo_meta',3);
}

Comment: With that you remove a hook, not the complete function. You can indeed remove the hook, and 're-hook' it with your own custom function. Be sure to prefix your own function so the name is unique.

Comment: So what's the simplest way to change this:   if ( in_array( 'date', $postinfo ) ) $postinfo_meta .= ' | ' . esc_html__('on',$themename) . ' ' . get_the_time( $date_format ); – Just to take away the ' | '  from the "meta" paragraph.

Comment: The simplest way is to edit the original function, but that's not the neatest way.. You can remove the hook, create your own function and re-hook with your own function.

Comment: This particular function doesn't appear to be hooked, is that possible?